# MySQL transaction - query altering database without commit?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to execute a series of different queries. Simply put, I need them all to execute successfully, or I need to have none of them execute.

At the moment, I do

```
mysql_query("SET autocommit=0;");
mysql_query("BEGIN;");
mysql_query("QUERY A");
if(mysql_error()){
    mysql_query("rollback;");
    die();
}
mysql_query("QUERY B");
if(mysql_error()){
    mysql_query("rollback;");
    die();
}else{
    mysql_query("commit;");
 }
```

The problem is that if I force query B to fail, I can still see the results of query A when looking at the database in phpmyadmin. Surely the query result should not be added to the database?

Comment: What engine are you using for your tables?

Comment: You have to make sure your tables are using a transactional storage engine (usualy InnoDB). Also there are some statements (LOCK TABLE for example) which will commit your transaction.

Comment: sorry, I am using InnoDB. EDIT - apparently I'm using MyISAM. Maybe that's my problem

Comment: yea MyISAM doesn't support transactions

Comment: oh dear. running `SHOW ENGINES` tells me that I don't have support for InnoDB. Perhaps this also explains why my foreign key constraints are broken. Looks like I need to look elsewhere for hosting. It seems ridiculous to me that there are databases that don't allow transactions or enforce foreign key constraints

Comment: Also note that even InnoDB doesn't support transactions for DDL statements that change schema. INSERTs and UPDATEs are fine, but ALTERs and CREATEs will automatically commit the transaction.

Comment: @theon, that's because the structure of the DB is stored in the `INFORMATION SCHEMA` which is stored in a seperate DB, which is not in InnoDB format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using MyISAM.
As is evident by the output of `SHOW ENGINES`.

MyISAM does not support transactions, nor does it support foreign key constraints.
You'll need to upgrade your MySQL version to one which supports InnoDB.
This will solve your issue.

I'm guessing your ISP is not helping you, maybe customer support can assist.